# Customizar cores de header para um &ionicPopup

Tags: ionic, ionic-popup

Estou procurando uma forma de alterar as cores do cabeçalho do **$ionicPopup** mas não encontrei nenhum material na internet. A única forma que encontrei foi se eu criar todo o meu template em um arquivo separado ou então inserir um código imenso dentro do parâmetro `template`.

Existe alguma forma de alterar a cor do header diretamente via parâmetro do **$ionicPopup**? se existe alguém pode me mostrar um exemplo por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei achando a solução. O **$ionicPopup** permite que eu utilize um conjunto de classes específicas a partir de um parâmetro chamado `cssClass`. Para resolver meu problema, eu abri o DOM do browser e identifiquei as classes que são definidas para montar o popup, em seguida, criei relacionamentos customizados em meu arquivo css que alteravam os elementos padrões do popup, assim:

```
.-positive .popup, 
.-popup-header-positive .popup .popup-head, 
.-popup-buttons-positive .popup .popup-buttons{
    border-color: #0c63ee;
    background-color: #387ef5;
    color: #fff;
}
.-popup-header-positive .popup .popup-title{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a compilação do ionic via SASS, para isso você deve ativar o modo de compilação do ionic com o comando:

```
$ ionic setup sass
```

dessa forma fica ativo o sass do ionic e você pode customizar em realtime, em tempo real o css de sua aplicação editando o arquivo:

```
./scss/ionic.app.scss
```

que se encontra na pasta raiz do app. Dessa maneira editando o arquivo ele já compila automaticamente os arquivos css da pasta www.

segue link de exemplo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_frPHsE2PZk

Comment: não quero usar sass, a minha intenção era, sempre que eu enviar o $ionicPopup eu poder definir uma classe para ele, e nessa classe eu definir suas configurações e semelhantes.